# where condition multiple values on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
create table testCondition(obj int, prop int, val nvarchar(255));
Go
insert into testCondition values(1, 10, 'A')
insert into testCondition values(1, 11, 'B')
insert into testCondition values(1, 12, 'C')
insert into testCondition values(2, 10, 'E')
insert into testCondition values(2, 11, 'B')
insert into testCondition values(2, 12, 'C')
```

This table holds 2M+ such records.
How to list all objects where (prop = 10 and val = 'A') and (prop = 12 and val = 'C')?

Expected output:

```
1, 10, 'A'
1, 12, 'C'
```

Comment: Why would the obj = 2, prop = 12, val = 'C' row not be expected?

Comment: To list the objects with ALL property values matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT 
    a.obj, a.prop, a.val 
FROM
    testCondition a
    JOIN (SELECT obj FROM testCondition WHERE (prop = 10 AND val = 'A')) AS b ON a.obj = b.obj
    JOIN (SELECT obj FROM testCondition WHERE (prop = 12 AND val = 'C')) AS c ON a.obj = c.obj
WHERE 
  ((prop = 10 AND val = 'A') OR 
  (prop = 12 AND val = 'C'))
```

The two `JOINS` ensure that we only grab the obj-ids where both conditions are true. We then filter out the unwanted rows with a valid obj id in the `WHERE` clause.

[Here's an example sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23b66/17)

Answer (score 1):

Use `OR`

```
...
WHERE (prop = 10 and val = 'A')
  OR  (prop = 12 and val = 'C')
```

**Edit**: now i understand, you want all rows for a given ID where both conditions are true. That's also the reason why you omit `2, 12, 'C'` since `2` does not have a row with `prop = 10 and val = 'A'`.

Then i would use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * FROM testCondition tc
WHERE (
  prop = 10 and val = 'A'
  AND EXISTS
  (
      SELECT 1 FROM testCondition tc2
      WHERE tc2.obj = tc.obj AND prop = 12 AND val = 'C'
  )
)
OR (
  prop = 12 and val = 'C'
  AND EXISTS
  (
      SELECT 1 FROM testCondition tc2
      WHERE tc2.obj = tc.obj AND prop = 10 AND val = 'A'
  )
)
```

Here's a demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8fe0c/2/0

Comment: In the expected output, Obj '2' should not be listed, since its Prop value does not satisfy the condition (Prop = 10 and txt = 'A')